# Is it valid to mix the "1 moc per thread" strategy with "child moc" strategy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Until now I always used a "main moc" for the main thread, initialised like this:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
```

and then I have `NSOperation` subclasses with their own moc that import data from the webservice, and I merge in the "main" moc on save observing `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`
But now I need the ability to add "temporary" objects that the user can commit (or not) later. So it looks like a child context is the perfect fit, and in order to use child context I changed the initialization of my "main moc" to

```
 [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
```

The question is: can my current structure with `NSOperation` subclasses with their own moc (initialised without a type in their own thread) have problems if used along with the child context strategy? I don't think so, but I don't find much about mixing those strategies.

Note that I want to maintain the `NSOperation` subclasses and I don't want to use child contexts also for importing my data, because it suffers on performances, see http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout

Moreover, when I create a new child of my main thread (that is of type `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`), can I create it that child with type `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`, continuing to work with my objects in the main thread as usual? Or am I forced to use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, and use `performBlock:` for every operation on my objects?
I'm asking because is not clear from the documentation if using 2 moc on the same thread (the main thread in this case) could be a problem.

**UPDATE**:
Finally I implemented and used this solution on production and there are not problems so far. The only thing that I needed to do is to avoid merging on my `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification when the moc has a `parentContext` (we don't want to merge mocs with a parent context, because they manage the merge themselves, but obviously the notification is triggered also for `save` on this kind of moc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple main queue context mocs, for exactly the reason you say - you create a temporary editing context for editing data which is then saved or discarded depending on user action.

As for mixing and matching with your operation queue contexts - that shouldn't be a problem. If you're merging back to the parent context, then any child contexts will pick up that data the next time they fetch.

Comment: Nice, I mainly asked for confirmation since it was not clear from the documentation, but it looked like it works. I'll mark the answer as accepted in the next couple of days. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that's indicated when working with multiple threads. Here, I've wrote an [article](http://cocoaexposed.com/post/93724926497/concurrent-programming-with-core-data) exactly about this. The slave mocs mentioned in it, are designed exactly for working with operations, each operations on it's own slave moc.

Comment: Nice article! Though don't you think "child" context sound so much... nicer than "slave"?

Comment: Yes, I'm already aware about the "child context" option, but the question is not just about it. It is more like this: "can I use both the child context and the 'old' way of 1 moc per thread + merging?"

Comment: @jrturton ha ha, no, slave is more explicit, they're doing all the work. Although I could have call them workers I suppose ...